# Should i Buy a new laptop or upgrade the old one?

Tags: laptop, hp-pavilion

I have a Hp pavilion g6 notebook with

```
configuration = processor i3-3110M @2.40ghz 
ram = 2gb
hard drive = 500gb sata 
Radeon 1gb graphics card
Os currently win 8.1
```

I bought it in june 2014. I barely used it since last year and it was great 
but now I'm into programming and software career. I need to run and use heavy development apps and it lags sometimes also the fan makes lot of noise on start up till 2 to 4 minutes and takes much time to completely refresh.

So should I buy a new laptop or upgrade this one?
And what upgrades should I do if I upgrade it?

Comment: This isn't really the place for product recommendations, but I'm going to say get a new one... If you are going to be using this for work it will just frustrate and slow you down. Working in IT I see the computer as a tool, and it must be of sufficient quality to do the job. Your not Web browsing and checking emails, this is your livelihood, invest in a quality, commercial grade piece of hardware with specs that should be good for 3 years plus. A $300 laptop won't cut it, my guess is you should be spending 3 times that or more.

Comment: Shoudn't this post get to "Hardware Recommendation"-Stackexchange?

Comment: According to HP (http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02770249.pdf) the HP Pavilion G6 series of laptops can support up to 8GB of RAM. That is arguably the best and perhaps only upgrade worth doing on an i3 system. If money is a concern and you don't want to replace your laptop right now, upgrading RAM will be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very difficult question to answer without knowing your budget or your specific needs. 
I will therefore make a series of assumptions and give answers for each of them.

The Buy options

- **You are using python to parse gigabytes worth of files for your job**

  - Your needs include durability, speed and portability.
  - You should probably buy a Lenovo ThinkPad one of the later generations and install a flavour of Ubuntu.
- **You are using VB or another language entirely dependent on windows to develop application for your job**

  - You require durability, speed and ability to process large amounts of data on windows.
  - A solid Win 10 desktop with around 10 GB RAM and an Intel i5 should suit your needs. You can port the applications to your workplace using your laptop.

  Then you have the upgrade options.

Please read http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02968997.pdf it's the manual for PC. Chapter 1 Part 1 indicates all supported processors and upgrades, these upgrades are fairly simple and help videos can be found on YouTube. HOWEVER upgrading individual components does not always turn out to be cheaper than buying a PC.